# Page break on each Group Category

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I'm using telerik reports and i'm facing a wall in front of me. i can't find page break and i have tried a lot today. 
I need to make a report that will change page in each category that i have as a group by. But i can't find a page break property on the group. 
Imagine that i have a report like this:
[Product catalog telerik example](http://demos.telerik.com/reporting/product-catalog/video.aspx)
But i need it to change page in each product category.
Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Look here. Same situation http://www.telerik.com/forums/insert-page-breaks-within-a-section

Answer (score 0):

Ok my bad. the page break exist in the property. sometimes it is in front of you and you can't find it.
take a look at the image:

[image: Page break property on telerik reporting]